# Show only one category in main query, issues on tag page

Tags: categories, functions, wp-query

I altered the following code from Ashfame:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'block_cat_query' );
function block_cat_query() {
global $wp_query;   
if( is_home() || is_search() || is_tag() ) {
    $wp_query->query_vars['cat'] = '3';
}
}
```

This code DOES work to filter posts from category #3 only on the home, search and tag pages.

However, I am utilizing

```
<?php single_tag_title(); ?>
```

in my header.php file and on specific tag pages, the tag title is not showing up. The page is instead showing the category title. This is only happening with this function in place, so I'm trying to figure out if there is another way of writing the function above that does not effect the use of `<?php single_tag_title(); ?>` on tag pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only issue you want to correct is the output of `single_tag_title`, you can correct the value via a filter by grabbing the tag query var directly:

```
function wpa90852_fix_tag_title(){
    $tag = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('tag'), 'post_tag' );
    return $tag->name;
}
add_filter( 'single_tag_title', 'wpa90852_fix_tag_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

There're a lot of methods [for the `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) that you can use to achieve your goal. If you want to block a category on:

- The `home` page
- The `Search`-results page
- On tag pages

by its ID, then you can use `category__not_in`.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse90852_block_cat_query' );
function wpse90852_block_cat_query( $query )
{
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $query;

    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_search() || $query->is_tag() ) )
    {
        $query->set( 'category__in', 3 );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, let me be more clear... I only want to SHOW category #3. And the function I originally posted does work, however tag pages are showing up as category pages. Does that make sense? For example, if I am looking at a specific tag page while logged in, the WP-admin bar shows "edit category" instead of "edit tag." And the tag name does not show up, but the category name. 

I'm just trying to figure out why the tag pages are showing up like they're category #3 pages.

Comment: @BethBlinebury What exactly are you trying to do: A) Public/Theme modification or B) modifiying the admin UI? If it's about themes, then see the update. If you're trying to query for a `category` with the `ID` of 3 _as well_ on _every_ of those listed pages, then you might want to go with `category__and`.

Comment: I'm trying to modify my theme. I tried the updated function you posted and it's throwing an error for 'set'

Comment: The original function I posted DOES work. It's just that I'm using <?php single_tag_title(); ?> in my header.php file and with that function, the single tag title is showing up as the category title. That's really the only issue I'm trying to resolve but I thought maybe a different way of writing it would do the trick.

Comment: @BethBlinebury Then **please** update your question with those _very specific_ details... And if you say "error", then please as well tell the _exact_ error description. Error is pretty vague by itself.

Comment: Sorry! I have updated my question.

The function you submitted output the following error message (line #37 is where $wp-query->set is located) -
    
Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on a non-object in /home/content/b/e/t/bethblindesign/html/allure/wp-content/themes/allurefilms/functions.php on line 37

Comment: Instead of `is_home() || is_search() || is_tag() )` use the `is_front_page()` conditional tag.

Comment: @BethBlinebury you forgot to add a parameter in your function `function block_cat_query($query)`

Comment: `$wp_query->set` should be `$query->set`.

Comment: Btw, you also have to check if it is the main_query, else you alter all queries on the main page.

Comment: Thanks again @kaiser - didn't mean to waste your time! I'll be more specific next time. New to the boards, sorry.

Comment: @Milo Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the right hook, here it is `pre_get_posts`. Then you have to check if you are on the front page (`is_front_page()`) and if you are in the main query (`is_main_query`). As the `$query` is given as a parameter it's easy to alter the query.

```
/**
 * WordPress Answers #90852
 *
 * @param obj $query WP_Query object
 * @return void
 * @author Ralf Hortt
 **/
function pre_get_posts_90873( $query )
{
    if ( is_front_page() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) :
        $query->query_vars['cat'] = 3;
    endif;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_90873' );
```

PS: Ok, I'll see the question has changed. I still let my answer her, just in case someone want to know.

Comment: Sorry Horttcore! Your code does work but I need it to filter on the tag pages as well. And my main issue is the use of the single tag title code.

Comment: Well it is not hard to alter the `if` clause to work on the tag page as well. Whats your problem with the single tag title?